# how does this update pattern perform for an index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen a few studies that compare how indexes handle insert/update load on monotonous increasing values (for example a column that indexes current timestamp) and random values (a column that indexes access tokens).  And that the. Former is much faster.

What about an index (user, document) where for each user, the document always increases monotonously?  For example,

```
 (user, document)
 0, 0
 0, 1
89, 0
0, 2
89, 1
```

How does this index perform for inserts and updates? Will it be faster than random inserts? I expect all queries to always include user. Is there a better way to index these?

Is this insert pattern studied explicitly?

Comment: If you have few users, it will be faster (the sub-index for each user will be built in increasing order)

Comment: You should always use the indexes you need, as this effect will most likely be _negligible_.